# CSS checkerboard component ignoring border radius

Tags: css, reactjs

I wanted a checkerboard background to represent transparency. I created a component that I can use anywhere that needs a checkered background, like this:

```
const Checker: React.FC = () => {

    const styles = reactCSSExtra({
        "default": {
            container: {
                position: "absolute",
                width: "inherit",
                height: "inherit",
                background: `repeating-conic-gradient(#808080 0% 25%, transparent 0% 50%) 50% / 10px 10px,
                             repeating-conic-gradient(#ffffff 0% 25%, transparent 0% 50%) 100% / 10px 10px`,
                opacity: 0.5,
                zIndex: -100,
            },
        },
    });

    return (
        <div style={styles.container}></div>
    );
}

export default Checker;
```

I use it by creating a container div in which I place the checker, and the rest of the components:

```
<div>
    <div> ...rest here </div>
    <Checker/>
</div>
```

All the components I am using the checker in have a 4px border radius applied to the top container however, the checker board does not seem to be affected by this. Even with an `overflow: hidden` applied to the container, the checker still seems to have some "artifacts":

[image: Showing gradient not being affected by border radius]
[image: Showing gradient not being affected by border radius]

In both pictures, the checker board completely ignores the border radius.

Sometimes, depending on the zoom level of the browser, it *will* be affected by the border radius. The pictures were taken at 500% zoom but at semi-regular intervals the border radius will affect the gradient, although I couldn't get it to happen now. It happens on both Chrome and Firefox.
I thought that it might just be a gradient issue but it also happens with different gradient checkerboards and even SVG based checker boards.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `position: relative;` on DIV (Content) wrapper and move **Checker** inside of that div.

```
<div>
    <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
    
      <Checker/> 
    
      ...rest here 
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it - still overflows over the div

Comment: I edited the answer, this should works now :)

Comment: I was going to say that that wouldn't work because it needs to be position absolute in order to have the two components overlap but while messing around I managed to fix it. I'm not sure what I did because it feels like I tried it all before but it is now working.
EDIT: Apparently it's caused by different component. If I disable it, the issue goes away.

Comment: Checker should still have position absolute. The solution was just to have position relative on the parent of Checker, that way checker absolute position cannot have more width than a parent, and parent is Content in this case.